# fake async function. Why?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I was reading this article on [howtonode](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick), 
but don't get why it's fake async ?

So fake async is described as:

```
function asyncFake(data, callback) {        
    if(data === 'foo') callback(true);
    else callback(false);
}

asyncFake('bar', function(result) {
    // this callback is actually called synchronously!
});
```

Correct code: always async

```
function asyncReal(data, callback) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        callback(data === 'foo');       
    });
}
```

My question is what's wrong with the first part of code ?
Why nextTick() can promise the 'right' effect ?...

Please explain to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing's *wrong* with the first case. However, it's just that you have to be proactive (as the developer) to know exactly what's happening in your code.

In the first case, you are not doing any I/O, and the `callback` is not actually being put into the Event Loop. It just the same as doing this:

```
if(data === 'foo')
 return true;
else 
 return false;
```

However, in second case, you *are* putting the callback into the event loop until the next iteration.

In terms of how things work, nothing's wrong. However, you *need* to be aware of what implications are.

For instance:

```
function maybeSync(a, cb) {
 if(a === 'a') {
   cb('maybeSync called');
 } else {
   // put the called into event-loop for the next iteration
   process.nextTick(function() {
     cb('maybeSync called');
   });
 } 
}

function definitelySync() {
 console.log('definitelySync called');
}

someAsync('a', function(out) {
  console.log(out);
});

definitelySync();
```

In the top case, which one gets called first?

If the input is "a" then the output is:

```
maybeSync called
definitelySync called
```

If the input is something else (e.g. not "a") then the output would be:

```
definitelySync called
maybeSync called
```

You need to make them consistent, as it would be easy to distinguish if the `callback` can be called sync/async based on the condition. Again comes back to being responsible, being consistent and being aware of what's happening in your code. =)

Answer (score 0):

In the async fake function - you can see that callback is called as a normal function invocation i.e in the same call stack.

1. someone calls async fake fn
2. async fake fn calls the callback passed to it
3. If that callback takes time to complete - the async fake fn is kept waiting i.e it remains in call stack.

By using process tick - we are just submitting the callback function to be scheduled for execution.

This process tick call completes immediately and the asyncreal will return immediately. Thus the callback will be executed in asynchronous way.